# Can I use the Savage Worlds Adventure Edition core rules with Interface Zero 2.0?

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition, interface-zero

I'm quite new/interested to the Savage Worlds game system, and I would like a game with a cyberpunk flavour so I ended up with Interface Zero 2.0.

Can I/Is it ok to use the latest edition of Savage Worlds (Savage Worlds Adventure Edition Core Rules) with Interface Zero 2.0?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, but with several changes

The core of the system remains the same, but there are *lots* of minor changes in the system that you have to be aware of. The ones that will most likely impact in your *Interface Zero* games being:

- No money, it uses a *Wealth* score to measure if you can buy something or not, while IZ has prices for everything. Converting without a good mastery of both systems will certainly be a pain;
- Skill changes, there are what is called "core skills" now, which are skills that everybody knows (like *Notice*). There are more skills in the game, and some skills got consolidated;
- The action system changed to a three action economy, rather than "standard" and "move" actions. Some rules in IZ will have to be changed because of that. This also affects how most firearms work.

Other than that, you can use most of IZ without big problems. However, do keep in mind that there is an [Interface Zero 3.0](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/821979583/interface-zero-30) in the works. All this trouble will be solved if you wait for it to be released.